# Wurde mal „uns“ großgeschrieben?

Tags: capitalization, personal-pronoun, reformed-orthography

Die Personalpronomen *du* und *euch* (zusätzlich zur Respektform *Sie*) wurden mal großgeschrieben. Wurde mal, auch wenn schon lange her, *uns* – dessen Anrede auch den Gesprächspartner einschließt – großgeschrieben?

> Wenn Du ankommst, können wir **Uns** treffen.

Oder:

> Wenn Sie ankommen, könnten wir **Uns** treffen.

Comment: Da kommt mir die Frage auf, kann man auch sich selber anreden?

Comment: "Du" und "Euch" können immer noch großgeschrieben werden. Es kommt immer auf den Kontext und wie der Satz vermittelt wird an. http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/gross-oder-kleinschreibung-von--em-du-du--em--und--em-ihr-ihr--em--1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Uns" im Pluralis Majestatis wurde nach der alten Rechtschreibung sicher großgeschrieben. Bei anderen "uns" kann ich mich an keine Großschreibung erinnern. Sie war sicher nie Standard in den letzten Jahrhunderten. Ich glaube, die Instanzen von "uns" neben dem Pluralis Majestatis werden nicht als analog zu "Er, Du, Sie, Ihr, Wir" aufgefasst, sondern als analog zu "ich". Demnach werden sie klein geschrieben.

Die neue Rechtschreibung muss ich noch recherchieren.

Comment: Die neue Rechtschreibung hat meines Wissens nur die Schreibung von *du* angepasst (großgeschriebenes *du* ist nicht mehr erlaubt).

Comment: So war es. Aber ich glaube nun darf man wieder. Sehr verwirrend. Und eine bodenlose Unverschämtheit alles durcheinander zu bringen, an das man ein Leben lang gewöhnt war! @Jan